# Remove excess CSS with CopyWebpackPlugin

Tags: javascript, web, webpack

I am doing something very similar to this code in my production webpack. How can I remove the excess CSS code being used from the CopyWebpackPlugin?

```js
Plugins: [
   new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css', to: 'css/'},
      { from: 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts', to: 'fonts/'}
   ])
]
```